# Angular Material App not loading after upgrading to version 7

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk, angular7

When I upgraded my app to version 7 of Angular, Angular Material and CLI.
**My app hangs on the loading screen.** After a lot of digging around I found the source of the issues, it has to do with **[BreakpointObserver](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) from Angular CDK.**

Here's the way to reproduce the issue:

- Create a new Angular 7 App
- ng add @angular/material
- Add the following getter in the AppComponent:

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  get height(): Observable {
      return this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset])
        .pipe(map(bp => bp.matches ? 100 : 50));
    }
- Add the following to an element in the AppComponent template:

  [style.minHeight.px]="height | async"

Anyone has an idea what's the problem here?
Is it a bug in Angular CDK?

I've already posted an issue in Angular issues:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26586

But the issue was closed as it was not acknowledged being a bug.

Comment: Are you using the correct TypeScript that's needed in Angular 7? Check https://update.angular.io/ for your needs.

Comment: It's most probably because you failed to provide a minimal reproduction of the problem. Do it. Use StackBlitz. Or at the very least a minimal github project reproducing the problem.

Comment: If it hangs, most probably you got error in the console.